# How to get a JSON object value that is randomly generated for each request?

Tags: json, perl

My problem is basically in that JSON.
I can't get the value of `bytes_on_disk` because the first object `2020-07-14T12:57:15.770557Z` is being generated randomly with each request:

```
{"2020-07-14T12:57:15.770557Z":{"requests_served":291575,"cache_hits":215441,"cache_misses":76134,"browser_cached":0,"bytes_sent":161829275429,"bytes_on_disk":29648157174}}

$json_data->{}->{bytes_on_disk};
```

Comment: Get the keys out and iterate them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know there's only going to be one key, then you can get it using the `keys()` function.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use JSON;

my $json = '{
  "2020-07-14T12:57:15.770557Z" : {
    "requests_served" : 291575,
    "cache_hits" : 215441,
    "cache_misses" : 76134,
    "browser_cached" : 0,
    "bytes_sent" : 161829275429,
    "bytes_on_disk" : 29648157174
  }
}';

my $json_data = JSON->new->decode($json);

my ($key) = keys %$json_data;

say $json_data->{$key}{bytes_on_disk};
```

Alternatively, you could simply it slightly by just getting the only value in the hash with `values()`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use JSON;

my $json = '{
  "2020-07-14T12:57:15.770557Z" : {
    "requests_served" : 291575,
    "cache_hits" : 215441,
    "cache_misses" : 76134,
    "browser_cached" : 0,
    "bytes_sent" : 161829275429,
    "bytes_on_disk" : 29648157174
  }
}';

my $json_data = JSON->new->decode($json);

my ($data) = values %$json_data;

say $data->{bytes_on_disk};
```